# how to use "referred" column

Tags: sql

This is the question:

> Retrieve all customers who were referred to the bookstore by another customer. List each customer's last name, and the number of the customer who made the referral. (the referred column)

This is my query:

```
    select lastname, referred
       from customers
       order by referred;
```

But this query returns customers that don't have a referral i.e. they have the referred column `(null)`, which means that they were never referred by another customer. How do I structure the query so that it only gives the customers who were referred by another customer?

here's the image link of the output:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/amtYc.jpg

Comment: `where referred is not null` maybe...?

Comment: He said blank, and blank can be != than null so he would have to either modify it to null or check for blank as `referred != ""`

Comment: @ForguesR - you mean add `WHERE referred != null` ?

Comment: If you have null values then you have to use `is not null` and not `!= null`.  If you have blank then you must use `!=''`.

Comment: Your first problem is that your referred column is not a integer, hence the fact it accepts empty blank entries, you should change it into a int field and if a referred does not exist set it to 0 if it exists set it to the referred number.

Comment: @Quasimodo'sclone in my course we haven't got to the `JOIN` queries yet. This is a question from the _Restricting rows and Sorting data_ chapter.

Comment: What is date structure? Show the `CREATE TABLE` command. Which DBMS is used? Are there redundant rows in *one* table? - customer1 referred by customer2 ; customer1 referred by customer3 ; customer1 referred by customer4 ... ? What's about IDs?

Comment: hey I got it to work, this query worked
`select lastname, referred
  from customers
  where referred is not null
  order by referred;`

Comment: @AlooGobi if your column was `INT` type and you were inserting data as something like `INSERT INTO customers (lastname, referred) VALUES ('lastname', NULL);` then using `IS NOT NULL` would work just fine, however if that column was `VARCHAR` or `CHAR` or any `STRING` type with an insert of `INSERT INTO customers (lastname, referred) VALUES ('lastname', '');` it would fall into as blank and not null.

Comment: Since this question for psychics does not provide useful information, you can delete it.

Comment: Which database server are you using? Oracle?

Comment: @AlooGobi also next time make sure you tell people what database you're using and not just SQL, in your case it seems ORACLE from the error you mentioned on one of the answers, since each database behaves differently a lot of what was said here could have been mistakenly said because of that information as people could have been basing their answers on for example MySQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make it like

**For only blank**

```
SELECT lastname, referred FROM customers WHERE referred != '' ORDER BY referred
```

**For NULL only**

```
SELECT lastname, referred FROM customers WHERE referred IS NOT NULL ORDER BY referred
```

**EDIT**

**For both blank and NULL**

```
SELECT lastname, referred FROM customers WHERE referred IS NOT NULL OR referred != '' ORDER BY referred;
```

Comment: Normalizing one's table is better than overflowing a query with unneeded checks.

Comment: @Prix Well he didn't told the structure of his table, so how can one identify the column can't be null and could you please suggest me what changes i should do here in these scenerio

Comment: By reading the question `they have the referred column blank` and blank is different than null.

Comment: in sql null means 'missing information and inapplicable information' and in other sense that is also same as blank

Comment: Really, then why does http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bab94/1 returns blank fields? Because blank is different than null. Having a a secondary check for blank fields proves that your field is being wrongly used and it should be changed into a proper data type such as in this case integer.

Comment: @AshishRajput - yes, the output was blank, if it was null, it would have said `(null)`

Comment: Well what i believe is NULL is a special case of blank and when someone say blank you can not ignore  NULL that is also means 'missing value', It's a different think SQL made a mechanism to handle NULL, anyway thanks for the fiddle, I am using it first time thanks!

Comment: @AshishRajput im confused now lol `WHERE referred IS NOT NULL` worked. you were right :)

Comment: @AlooGobi check your field data type and how you're inserting the data into it. If `IS NOT NULL` worked then your field was no blank, you lacked on providing information such as your table structure and your insert query is or needs to be different as well.

Comment: @AlooGobi Please update your question as suggested by Prix otherwise i am going to get -1 again and again  :)

Comment: @AshishRajput aha! will do, mate

Answer (score 1):

I think u can try this

```
select lastname, referred from customers WHERE referred<>'';
```

Comment: gave me a **SQL Error: ORA-01741: illegal zero-length identifier** error

Comment: @Prix output: **no rows selected**

Comment: @AlooGobi its showing me the result just as expected.

Comment: @AlooGobi Its returning 5 records. Which i believe is correct

Comment: Thanks @Prix for sqlfiddle. You are awesome.

Answer (score 0):

If `referred` accepts NULL values, then add `WHERE referred IS NOT NULL` after the `FROM` clause.

If it doesn't accept NULL values, then add `WHERE referred <> [value you take as meaning "not referred"]`

Answer (score 0):

`WHERE ... IS NOT NULL` should work, so:

```
SELECT lastname, 
       referred
  FROM customers
 WHERE referred IS NOT NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

Since each customer could refer multiple customers and can be referred by multiple customers, this is a n:m relation. There should be another table managing the relationship. Then you have to query a `JOIN` with `GROUP BY` clause. Number of referrers can be retrieved by the aggregate function `COUNT()`. You should provide the complete data structure for detailed help.